# What is the best way to disrupt rock slope landslides?

Tags: geotechnical-engineering

[image: A diagram representing a rock slide]

From my understanding, landslides and other erosion occurs along various natural formations in the geologic bed, such that all the organic material above some **geologic strong point** fails, and all the organic and inorganic material above the bed slide freely to devastating effect.

Are there any known techniques to encourage the formation of new **geologic strong points** that would be considered safe from erosion?

In a more practical sense i would like to know if there are well-known ways to safely and sustainably add mass to a landscape, such as that shown in the image above (of a steep cliff failing and a rock-slide ocurring); that would be considered safe and effective for preventing future landslides and erosion events?

*Plants / animals / fungi naturally add biomass to these types of landscapes each year and so sustainability in this sense requires considering these natural processes along with the more destructive forces of nature.*

Comment: Don't dig the support away.

Comment: lots of concrete

Answer (score 1):

One starts with:

- A geotechnical report that investigates the geology, the structure of the soil layers, and whether there is a Seismic fault near the site. type of layers, bedding angles, shear values, and historical information going back possibly to thousands of years. The list of studies of the hazards and scope of this report is site dependent.
- Next step is a soil engineering study, a battery of drilled test holes, and sometimes the use of explosive P-wave reflection imaging that can penetrate kilometers deep. The same report will advise on methods for stabilizing and retaining tailored for the site including a recommendation to use one or a mix of the following noninclusive ways:
- Removal and replacement of weak or soapy material with engineered fill.
- Horizontal nailing of the slope with concrete bulkhead or shotcrete.
- Retaining walls, steel, concrete, or a mix of these, or retaining structures such as the ones that shoulder mountainous freeways or pier structures.

It is an expansive field of civil engineering and may require the collaboration of many specialties.